# Disable camera shaking in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, camera-calibration

I am creating simple camera app and I want to add 'image stability' so when hands are shaking the camera does not twitch. Is it possible to do in iOS?

Comment: See if this helps. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureConnection/videoStabilizationEnabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by getting the raw image from the camera, and only using a subset of the raw image frame, then programmatically picking a new subset for each raw image to use for the next frame. Needless to say, this is a large amount of work and should only be undertaken if you know what you are doing or want to have the most impressive video/picture taking app.

The iPhone 6+ has this built into the hardware and is, I believe, what the previous comment link to avfoundation is talking about.